# Enviar un email adjuntando multiples archivos

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo un ejercicio en el cual, tengo que seleccionar a los usuarios de una tabla, crear para cada uno un PDF con su curriculo y para acabar enviar a alguien un email en el que adjunto todos los PDF creados.

Primero, el formulario:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header"><h5>Enviando un PDF con el curriculo de los usuarios con experiencia laboral.</h5></div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="pdf_empresa" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Correo Electronico de la empresa</label>

                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="sector" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Sector en que los empleados deben tener experiencia</label>

                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <select id="sector" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('sector') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="sector" value="{{ old('sector') }}" required autofocus>
                                    @foreach($sectores as $sector)
                                        <option value="{{$sector->nombre}}">{{$sector->nombre}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>

                                @if ($errors->has('sector'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('sector') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Enviar Curriculo
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Despues, la función que maneja mi petición:

```
public function envio(EnvioRequest $request){
        $usuarios=User::whereHas('experiencias',function($query) use ($request){
            $query->where('sector_empresa',$request->sector);
        })->get();

        if(count($usuarios)==0)
            return back()->with('message',['danger','No hay ningun usuario con experiencia en el sector '.$request->sector.'.']);
        else{
            foreach($usuarios as $usuario){
                $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.curriculo', compact('usuario'));
                $salida=$pdf->output();
                $ruta='C:/xampp/htdocs/bolsa/public/descargas/'.'Curriculo de '.$usuario->name." ".$usuario->second_name.'.pdf';
                file_put_contents($ruta, $salida);
            }
            Mail::to($request->email)->send(new Adjuntar($request->sector)); // Se ha conseguido que los PDF se creen y se ha conseguido enviar el email. Solo queda que los emails se adjunte.
            return back()->with('message',['success','Se ha enviado a la empresa un email con el PDF adjunto.']);
        }
    }
```

El archivo Mail:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Adjuntar extends Mailable{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $sector;

    public function __construct($sector){
        $this->sector=$sector;
    }

    public function build(){
        return $this->view('correo.adjunto');
    }
}
```

Puedo hacer que se creen multiples PDF con el curriculo de cada usuario y puedo despues enviar un email, pero aun no se como adjuntarlos en dicho email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debe almacenar su correo electrónico generado en una variable y simplemente agregar varios archivos adjuntos, como este:

```
public function build()
{
    $email = $this->view('correo.adjunto')->subject('Curriculum');

    // $archivosadjuntos es una matriz con rutas de archivos de archivos adjuntos
    foreach($archivosadjuntos as $rutaArchivo){
        $email->attach($rutaArchivo);
    }
    return $email;
}
```

En este caso, su variable $archivosadjuntos debe ser una matriz con rutas a archivos:

```
$archivosadjuntos= [
    // primer archivo adjunto
    '/path/to/file1',

    // Segundo archivo adjunto
    '/path/to/file2',
    ...
];
```

---

También puede adjuntar archivos no solo por rutas de archivos, sino con el tipo MIME y el nombre de archivo deseado, consulte la documentación sobre el segundo

> Caso de uso para el método `attachment`:
>
> - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#attachments
> - https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#attachments

Por ejemplo, su matriz $archivosadjuntos puede ser algo como esto:

```
$archivosadjuntos= [
    // primer archivo adjunto
    'path/to/file1' => [
        'as' => 'file1.pdf',
        'mime' => 'application/pdf',
    ],

    // Segundo archivo adjunto
    'path/to/file12' => [
        'as' => 'file2.pdf',
        'mime' => 'application/pdf',
    ],

    ...
];
```

Después de que pueda adjuntar archivos de esta matriz:

```
// $archivosadjuntos es una matriz con rutas de archivos de archivos adjuntos
foreach($archivosadjuntos as $rutaArchivo=> $fileParameters){
    $email->attach($rutaArchivo, $fileParameters);
}
```

> Fuente SO:  [Attach Multiple Files To Mailables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42849520/8933039)

---

También puedes usar un bucle para todos los archivos adjuntos.

Algo como esto:

```
$data_mail = Mail::send($tmp, array('msg'=>$msg), function($message) use ($ruta) {
    $message->from('xxx@example.com', $_POST['subj']);
    $message->to($_POST['to'])->subject($_POST['subj']);
    $size = sizeOf($ruta); //obtener el recuento de la cantidad de archivos adjuntos

    for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        $message->attach($ruta[$i]);
    }
},true);
```

Comment: Pues gracias. He conseguido por fin crear multiples ficheros PDF y adjuntarlos en un recien creado email.